# Zend Studio 10: New PHPUnit Test Case Error Regarding PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase Extension

Tags: phpunit, zend-studio

I am attempting to set up some PHPUnit test cases in Zend Studio but am stuck on the "New PHPUnit Test Case" form.  The error I get is:

```
There are several elements with the name 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' in project 'espnova'. 
Click 'Browse...' to choose one
```

When I browse, I only have one PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase to choose from.  In the image below you can see the "New PHPUnit Test Case" form Im talking about.

[image: New PHPUnit Test Case form]

I think the Superclass value is the one giving me the error so I click Browse and I get this when I search for PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase:

[image: Element selection form]

Answer (score 0):

Do a code search for all directories included in your build path. If you are including a PEAR library AND the PHPUnit package is somewhere in your project then Zend-studio will not know which one to select.